# Stuck on method to compare 2 int** in C

Tags: c

I am stuck on this method and I cannot find my bug. The description of the method and my code are below:

This function takes 2 int**.  It compares the integers being pointed
at, and then sets the pointers to the address of the smaller of the
two integers.  If the values are equal, both pointers should be set to
the address of the first pointer.

Either of the pointers being passed in might point to NULL instead of
a valid integer - in that case the other value is implicitly the
smallest and both pointers should be set to point to the non-null
value.  You can assume both pointers will not be NULL.

```
void point_to_smallest_ptr(int** first, int** second) 
{
    int* ptr1;
    int* ptr2;
    ptr1 = *first;
    ptr2 = *second;

    if(ptr1 == NULL)
    {
        ptr1 = ptr2;
    }
    else if(ptr2 == NULL)
    {
        ptr2 = ptr1;
    }

    else if(*ptr1 <= *ptr2)
    {
        ptr2 = ptr1;
    }

    else
    {
        ptr1 = ptr2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: get rid of `ptr1` and `ptr2` entirely.

Comment: " takes 2 int**. It compares the integers being pointed at" is a problem.  `first` and `second` do not point to `int`.  They point to `int *`.  Please explain the goal better.

Answer (score 0):

"This function takes 2 int**." they are `first` and `second`, pointers to pointers to `int`.

"the integers being pointed at" are `**first` and `**second`.

"... then sets **the pointers** to ..." are `*first` and `*second`, the pointers to `int` are meant, obviosly not `first` and `second`, which are the pointers to the targeted pointers to `int`. Having pointers to the targeted pointers, instead of only copies of the targeted pointers, is what allows you to actually modify the targeted pointers to `int`.

"... the address of the smaller of the two integers ..." is the value you find in one of the pointers to int, i.e. either `*first` or `*second`. To find out which of the two you need to compare the ìnt`s, i.e. something like` (**first < **second)`.

"should be set to the address of the first pointer" I think is confusing, I'd expect the phrasing "should be set to the address of the first int" or "should be set to the address found in the the first pointer to int". But from context it is quite clear what is meant.